# Can <% if %> Use Integers?

Tags: php, templates, silverstripe

I'd like to use a SilverStripe 3 template conditional based on an integer return like this:

`<% if $Variable.count = 1 %>`

Is that possible? It doesn't seem to work when I try it and the documentation talks only about literals inside "" with ==.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when done properly, no when you're doing it that way. 1 = means you're assigning 1 to the variable, which will always be true. 2 ='s (==) is a comparison operator. 3 (===) is a type comparison operator.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: And right you are. I often get confused about what is PHP syntax and what is SilverStripe template syntax. I should default to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes. But I can't remember the last time I've done it. Looking at the doc you should be able to do:
http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/3.1/reference/templates

```
<% if $Variable.count == "10" %>
    ...
<% end_if %>
```

like @aynber said, make sure to use `==` and number (might) have to have quotes around.

Comment: OK, got it. It takes ``` <% if $Variable.count == 10 %>```. Thanks for the help.